# dovecot: Force TCP socket disconnect on imap login failure?

Tags: login, authentication, socket, dovecot, imap

I'm running `dovecot 2.2.13` under `Debian 8`.

I'd like to force an immediate TCP socket disconnect after any imap login attempt that fails.

Right now, if invalid credentials are supplied during an imap login, the client can keep retrying logins with different credentials. However, I want to prevent that from occurring by causing the imap socket connection to be closed as soon as there is any failed login attempt.

I haven't been able to find any `dovecot` configuration setting which could control this behavior, but I'm hoping that I just missed something.

Thank you very much for any suggestions.